# How to set divider and divider color with PopupMenu Item in flutter?

Tags: flutter

In this simple implementation code I added some *PopupMenuButton* items into *AppBar* actions argument and now I want to styling *PopupMenuDivider* color which that have default color.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do this very easily using the Theme class, using which you can change the icon color, text color and PopupMenuDivider color.

Again, you can easily do this on Divider at PopupMenuItem using PopupMenuDivider.

```
appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("PopUpMenu Flutter"),
    centerTitle: true,
    actions: [
      Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
          dividerTheme: DividerThemeData(
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
          textTheme: TextTheme().apply(bodyColor: Colors.white),
        ),
        child: PopupMenuButton<int>(
          color: Colors.indigo,
          //onSelected: (item) => onSelected(context, item),
          itemBuilder: (context) => [
            PopupMenuItem<int>(
              value: 0,
              child: Text('Settings'),
            ),
            PopupMenuDivider(),
            PopupMenuItem<int>(
              value: 1,
              child: Text('Share'),
            ),
            PopupMenuDivider(),
            PopupMenuItem<int>(
              value: 2,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.logout),
                  const SizedBox(width: 8),
                  Text('Sign Out'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: Thank you so much,

Comment: All I wanted was this code and you mentioned everything.

Comment: you are most welcome, best of luck

Answer (score 3):

Do like this:

```
class CustomPopupMenuDivider extends PopupMenuDivider {

  final double? thickness;
  final double? indent;
  final double? endIndent;
  final Color? color;

  const CustomPopupMenuDivider({
    super.height,
    super.key,
    this.thickness,
    this.indent,
    this.endIndent,
    this.color,
  }) : super();

  @override
  State<CustomPopupMenuDivider> createState() => _CustomPopupMenuDividerState();
}

class _CustomPopupMenuDividerState extends State<CustomPopupMenuDivider> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Divider(
      height: widget.height,
      thickness: widget.thickness,
      indent: widget.indent,
      endIndent: widget.endIndent,
      color: widget.color,
    );
  }
}
```

then you can use this class instead of PopupMenuDivider

Answer (score 2):

You can use `PopupMenuItem child` and assign `Column` like

```dart
 PopupMenuItem<WhyFarther>(
              value: WhyFarther.harder,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text('Working a lot harder'),
                  Divider(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: I've tried this way, but I can't divide it further